# Como adicionar uma campo computado com valor baseado em expressão no MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta no MongoDB onde eu tenho a lista de usuários, com uma coluna date que indica a ultima vez que que o usuário ficou online. Nessa consulta, baseado na data e hora que o usuário ficou online eu gostaria de adicionar uma nova coluna `$addFields` com a informação se o usuário está online, ausente ou offline.

Os meus critérios seriam mais ou menos assim:

- Se a ultima vez que o usuário ficou online foi a 1 minuto atras, então está online.
- Se a ultima vez que o usuário ficou online foi a 2 minuto atras, então está ausente.
- Se a ultima vez que o usuário ficou online foi a 3 minuto atras, então está offline.

Minha estrutura de dados é a seguinte:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5ee191a8b3455000060c8296'),
  nome: 'Fulano'
  session_active: 2020-07-03T08:52:48.428+00:00
}
```

O resultado que eu esperava seria algo do tipo:

Hora do servidor: 08:52

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5ee191a8b3455000060c8296'),
  nome: 'Fulano'
  session_active: 2020-07-03T08:52:00.428+00:00,
  status: 'Online'
}
```

Hora do servidor: 08:52

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5ee191a8b3455000060c8296'),
  nome: 'Fulano'
  session_active: 2020-07-03T08:53:00.428+00:00,
  status: 'Ausente'
}
```

Hora do servidor: 08:52

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('5ee191a8b3455000060c8296'),
  nome: 'Fulano'
  session_active: 2020-07-03T08:54:00.428+00:00,
  status: 'Offline'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você quer é adicionar um *campo computado*, cujo valor virá da *computação* de valores já existentes.

Você pode utilizar um recurso chamado [*Aggregation Pipeline*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) para fazer isso, que possui alguns estágios (chamado de *stage* pela documentação) em que algumas transformações são feitas nos documentos em trabalho.

Você pode utilizar o [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) *aggregation stage* para adicionar um campo derivado da computação de outros valores já existentes. Funciona assim:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      currentDate: new Date()
    }
  }
]);
```

Com a operação acima, o MongoDB irá retornar todos os dados de `collection` com o campo `currentDate` definido para a data em que a operação foi realizada.

Assim, pode-se usar o operador [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch) para definir o comportamento de criação do campo computado `status`. Ficaria algo assim:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      // Adiciona o campo `status`:
      status: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $gt: [
                  '$session_active',
                  // Data atual menos um minuto.
                  new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 1)
                ]
              },
              then: 'Online'
            },
            {
              case: {
                $gt: [
                  '$session_active',
                  // Data atual menos dois minutos.
                  new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 2)
                ]
              },
              then: 'Ausente'
            }
          ],
          default: 'Offline'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Após isso, você pode utilizar o [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) *aggregation stage* para realizar outras eventuais filtrações.

#### Referência

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407898/are-there-computed-fields-in-mongodb

Comment: Luiz Felipe, muito obrigado por sua contribuição. Ela foi de total ajuda e resolveu o problema no qual eu estava buscando a solução.